# Partail View Render issue on dropdown change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am facing an issue while rendering the partial view on dropdown change. The issue is, while i change the value of dropdown , only partail view is loading, view ui is not displaying in page.

Please find my code below:

***index.cshtml:***

```
<h2>Cavity</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Cavity", "Cavity", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "getCavities" }))
{
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:5%">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <select name="ddlSite" id="ddlSite" onchange="getCavities();" class="form-control">

            <option value="-1">Select Site</option>

                            @if ((Model != null) && (Model.Sites != null))
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.Sites)
                {
                    if (Model.SiteID != null)
                    {
                        if (Model.SiteID == item.SiteID)
                        {
                            <option value="@item.SiteID" selected="selected" onchange="">@item.SiteName</option>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <option value="@item.SiteID" onchange="">@item.SiteName</option>
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <option value="@item.SiteID" onchange="">@item.SiteName</option>
                    }

                }
            }
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-1">

    </div>
</div>


   }

  <div id="cavitypartial" style="display:none">
   Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialView"); 
  </div>
```

**drop down calling function:**

```
 function getCavities()
{
    debugger;
    var id = document.getElementById("ddlSite").value;
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Cavity", "Cavity")',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: { id: id },
        UpdateTargetId: "cavitypartial",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
            $('#cavitypartial').html(data);
            $('#cavitypartial').fadeIn('fast');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert('An Error occurred while processing the request');

        }
    });


}
```

**My controller functionality:**

```
  public ActionResult Cavity(short? id)
    {

      // my functionality
      return PartialView( "_MyPartailViewName",model);
    }
```

**and finally below is partial view**

```
<div id="cavTable">


@if (Model != null && Model.ProdLineBySite != null && Model.CavityBySite != null && Model.Cavities != null && Model.Cavities.Count > 0)
{

    <table id="CavityTable" class=" table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Cavity Name</th>
            <th>Number of Cavities</th>

            @foreach (var item in Model.ProdLineBySite)
            {
                <th>@item.ProductLineName (CT/sec)</th>
            }

        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.CavityBySite)
        {
            //using (Ajax.BeginForm("CavityUpdate", "Cavity", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "tblCavity" }, new { data_ajax_mode = "replaceWith" }))
            //using (Ajax.BeginForm("CavityUpdate", "Cavity", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "tblCavity" }))
            {


                <tr id="@item.CavityID">

                    <td><a onclick='DeleteRow(this,@item.CavityID);'><img src='/Content/Images/trash_empty.png' class='btndelete' alt='x' /></a><a onclick='EditRow(this,@item.CavityID);'><img src='~/Content/Images/edit.png' class='btndelete' alt='x' /></a></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="cn_@item.CavityID" name="cn_@item.CavityID" value="@item.CavityName" disabled /></td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="cp_@item.CavityID" name="cp_@item.CavityID" class="addcavity" value="@item.NumberOfParts" disabled /> <input type="hidden" id="h_@item.CavityID" name="h_@item.CavityID" /> </td>
                    @foreach (var Cavitem in Model.Cavities)
                    {
                        if (item.CavityID == Cavitem.CavityID)
                        {
                            <td><input type="text" id="c_@(item.CavityID)p_@(Cavitem.ProductLineID)" name="c_@(item.CavityID)p_@(Cavitem.ProductLineID)" class="addcavity" value="@Cavitem.Time" disabled /></td>
                        }

                    }
                    <td><input type="text" id="cp_@item.comments" name="cp_@item.comments" class="addcavity" value="@item.comments" disabled /> <input type="hidden" id="h_@item.CavityID" name="h_@item.CavityID" /> </td>
                    <td id="Savecommand"><input type="submit" id="btnS_@item.CavityID" value="Save" disabled /></td>
                    <td id="Savecommand"><input type="button" id="btnC_@item.CavityID" onclick="cancelEditing(this,@item.CavityID);" value="Cancel" disabled /></td>


                </tr>
            }

        }
    </table>
}
```

Problem is only partailview is displaying in tha page not both(View & PartialView). i have tried the ajax container update id , but it doestn solve my proble.

Could you anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Using `getCavities` function you have updating the whole page so that it displaying only the partial view. I hope the following example will help you. I have updating the partial view during the dropdown change event

**Main page**

```
<h2>MainPage</h2>

select : <select id="ddlSite">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
        </select>

<div id="partialViewContainer">

</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#ddlSite").change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/DisplayPartialView",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                data: { id: $("#ddlSite").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#partialViewContainer').html(data);                    
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult MainPage()
{
   return View();
}

public PartialViewResult DisplayPartialView(int ID)
{
    return PartialView(ID);
}
```

Using jquery I have updating the **partialViewContainer** during dropdown event change. It will update only the partialViewContainer.

Comment: Hi Golda, Thanks For your reply. It's working fine. But am wondering why the same code is not working in server. In server only partial view is rendering instread of both.  Please tell some suggestions if you know how to overcome that.

Comment: You are updating your partial view in 'cavitypartial'. That is a ID of form. So that it updating the whole page